# Edible macroalgae?

Tags: marine-biology

I know that kelp is edible because [the concept of eating kelp is all over the interwebs](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=eating+kelp).  However, there is *incredibly little* information available online about what species of "seaweed" is edible.  I specifically am currently staying on Lake Geneva, and would be especially interested in edibility information about plants living in the lake, such as [starry stonewort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitellopsis_obtusa).  However, given the seeming general lack of information about the subject online, I would love to know about any common species of easily-accessible (e.g. by skin-diving) seaweeds that are edible and have any manner of nutritional value.

What species of seaweeds are edible?

Comment: [this paper](http://www.cipel.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Macrophytes-LEMAN_2009_Rapport.pdf) has a nice list of species found in Lake Geneva.  Most prominent are the Chara, Nitellopsis and Potamogeton genera.  Apparently Chara and Nitellopsis are common invasive species all over the place.  Information specifically regarding the edibility of these would be most valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Edible (marine) seaweeds with nutrition facts:

- Kelp: [Kombu](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/45077293?fgcd=&manu=&format=&count=&max=25&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=kombu&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=), [Arame](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/45315842?fgcd=&manu=&format=&count=&max=25&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=arame&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=), [Wakame](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/11669?fgcd=&manu=&format=&count=&max=25&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=seaweed&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=)
- Red alge: [Nori](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/45362654?fgcd=&manu=&format=&count=&max=25&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=nori&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=), [Dulse](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/45241361?fgcd=&manu=&format=&count=&max=25&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=dulse&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=), [Irish moss](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/11444?fgcd=&manu=&format=&count=&max=25&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=seaweed&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=), [Laver](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/11446?fgcd=&manu=&format=&count=&max=25&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=seaweed&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=)
- [Hijiki](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/45362478?fgcd=&manu=&format=&count=&max=25&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=hijiki&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=)

Other types of edible marine seaweed:

- Red algae: Carrageen moss
- Green algae: Sea lettuce
- More edible seaweeds with pictures on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edible_seaweed) on [Food and Agriculture Organization](http://www.fao.org/3/y4765e/y4765e0b.htm)

Freshwater macro algae are often toxic ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edible_seaweed), [Biology Libre Texts](https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Microbiology/Book%3A_Microbiology_(Boundless)/17%3A_Industrial_Microbiology/17.4%3A_The_Microbiology_of_Food/17.4E%3A_Edible_Algae)). [Starry stonewort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitellopsis_obtusa) does not appear to be edible, either.